# How to detect which sim card is in use

Tags: android

I  am new to android and am making an app to send messages programmatic-ally . Since, I couldn't find a way to detect which SIM is used to send an SMS or that Dual SIM wasn't supported or applicable, my question is:

**Is there a way to block a SIM Card in one's android phone?** By "block" I mean, `SIM_STATUS` is returned to `false` by some means without actually removing the SIM from the SIM slot? Like, it stays there but is not ready to be used. Also, can i do the opposite?
And all this programmatic-ally without doing anything to the phone on manual basis.

Answer (score 0):

By default android does not supported dual SIM.  but 
if u set default SIM for sms from android setting . your application will always send SMS from your default SIM

Comment: no, it doesn't work that way. My phone sends SMS from the card in Slot1 no matter what i do to it. Default settings work for built-in Android messaging only.

Comment: since dual SIM support is provided by phone manufacture, not by Google, this behavior can be different for each manufacture.

Comment: can you tell me what i can do for a QMobile?

Comment: Since it can be detected that whether a mobile is Dual Sim or not (by Java Reflection), is there a way to block a Sim of a specified ID or IMEI number or something like that?